# Leadbolt implement error

Tags: android, leadbolt

I have been trying to implement Leadbolt ads in my app but I am unable to set the Adlistener on the Controller. The methods I can add are nothing like the methods described in the [pdf](http://www.leadbolt.com/docs/Leadbolt_android_app_ad_guide_v400.pdf).
I can display ads in my app, but cannot use listeners.

This is my code:

```
 final Activity act = this;
                  myController = new AdController(act, MY_LB_SECTION_ID, new AdListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                  });

                  myController.loadAd();
```

The error I get is: *The constructor AdController(Activity, String, new AdListener(){}) is undefined*

This is the code from the [pdf](http://www.leadbolt.com/docs/Leadbolt_android_app_ad_guide_v400.pdf) file, but these methods seem to be unknown for eclipse:

```
final Activity act = this;
AdController myController = new AdController(act, 
"MY_LB_SECTION_ID", new AdListener() {
public void onAdLoaded() {
}
public void onAdClicked() {
}
public void onAdClosed() {
act.finish();
}
public void onAdCompleted() {
act.finish();
}
public void onAdFailed() {
act.finish();
}
public void onAdProgress() {
}
public void onAdAlreadyCompleted() {
act.finish();
}
public void onAdHidden() {} // function is deprecated
public void onAdPaused() {
act.finish();
}
public void onAdResumed() {
}
});
myController.loadAd();
```

Any ideas, what am I doing wrong?
I haven't added anything to the Manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Leadbolt:

It turned out that com.pad.android.listener.AdListener; or com.Leadbolt.AdListener; collided with import com.google.ads.AdListener; which is the AdMob AdListener. That's why I couldn't add the import statement.

You should extend your documentation, so if your listener collides with any other ad networks, how to use it, because it's not obvious. MobFox is also using com.adsdk.sdk.AdListener.

To use your AdListener while using other ad networks' AdListeners, this is how my first line looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdListener, com.google.ads.AdListener {
```

The first one is **MobFox**, the second one is **AdMob**. I didn't implement **leadbolt's** AdListener, because I am using it in the code:

```
AdController myController = new AdController(act, MY_LB_SECTION_ID_BANNER_ALL, new com.pad.android.listener.AdListener() {
```

This way it's working.

Answer (score 0):

From the PDF you referenced:

> Once this code is included, access your publisher portal and add an
>   “App Ad (SDK)” section and use the get code icon to retrieve the value
>   for “MY_LB_SECTION_ID”.

`MY_LB_SECTION_ID` is the integer ID, not a string.

Comment: What do you mean? I declared it as `String MY_LB_SECTION_ID = "885300128";` and I am using it as  `myController = new AdController(act, MY_LB_SECTION_ID, new AdListener()`.

Comment: I can't see that in your question, and the error is clear `The constructor AdController(Activity, String, new AdListener()`.  You are passing an activity reference, a String reference and an AdListener instance to the constructor.  The second argument is MY_LB_SECTION_ID and the compiler is saying it's a String.  Please put a breakpoint on this line `myController = new AdController(act, MY_LB_SECTION_ID, new AdListener() {` and inspect MY_LB_SECTION_ID

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, as I also use AdMob simultaneously but I found an easier way to fix this.

**Instead of using:**

```
AdController ad = new AdController(act, "MY_LB_SECTION_ID", new AdListener() {
    ...
}
```

**I used:**

```
AdController ad = new AdController(act, "MY_LB_SECTION_ID", new com.<leadbolt_package_name>.AdListener() {
    ...
}
```

Keeping into consideration that I used this import:

```
import com.<leadbolt_package_name>.AdController; // in my case, it was something like 'fgadcbgxysr'
```

This will read directly the LeadBolt library method and not the colliding one.
Hope it helps other users, though my response came late.